How to trigger an Event or AWS Lambda function if all AWS Glue Jobs are executed successfully
I have automated execution of 50 AWS Glue Jobs via AWS Step functions.
They all execute concurrently.
I would appreciate it, if someone can provide guidance on
How can I trigger either an event, aws lambda function or an
aws step function if all 50 glue jobs are executed successfully.
For reference
I do have an EventBridge rule that captures an AWS glue job failure
and sends notification via SNS.
There's an option to create an EventBridge rule that captures single job successful event but not for multiple job.
Thanks

"I have automated execution of 50 AWS Glue Jobs via AWS Step functions." so really, you want to know if the entire step function was successful, right?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/eventbridge-integration.html#event-detail-execution-status-change. Alternately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608840/aws-step-functions-wait-until-all-jobs-under-a-trigger-are-finished-before-pro

@erik258 Thanks for your comment. I appreciate it. I would like to know if all 50 glue jobs within a step function are triggered and finished successfully and then trigger something. The jobs are triggering and running fine without issue. I want to trigger an event or a lambda function if all 50 glue job runs are scucessful.

You can use AWS Step functions, have your glue jobs in an Map iterator, and then trigger lambda function when all the glue jobs are successful.  Please show the step function definition for more.
